# how to replace JNDI lookup with Spring framework to retrieve dataSource

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jndi

My Current project backend code is filled with these jndi lookups just to retrieve datasource

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
Datasource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("Build Datasource");
```

I'm wondering what is the easiest way to instead use Spring and get the dataSource object.

I tried this and it doesn't seem to work

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="Build Datasource"/>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

(is above approach correct way to do and not working only because my local tomcat JNDI is messed up?)

What is the best way to avoid using manual lookups all over the code and just get the datasource magically from Spring?

Comment: `<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="Build Datasource"/>` is standard way that we use in our project to lookup using JNDI. What is the issue that you are running into while that?

Comment: thanks for the reply - yes this does work - I had issues in my local tomcat instance. It works good now.